# Need to Protect json files in Drupal 7

Tags: json, .htaccess, drupal

I tried htacess module for protecting json which is placed in the path  www.example.com/site/all/themes/mytheme/my.json. It never worked for me.

When someone access this link they are able to easy read the content of the json file.

Can anyone suggest a good method to protect my json file in drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

Place json file in one directory and protect it with .htaccess or some other way (file permissions) so it can't be served by web server.

Then (in some other dir maybe) create simple php file which will read (through file system, where access will be allowed) and print out that file. Add json header if you need it. Also add some simple authentication at beginning of php file. Something like:

```
<?php

if ($_GET['password'] != 'fdsfsf23#rsd$f2') die;
```

This way json can be accessed only if valid password parameter is passed.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you to store private data in json files located in your public directories. If you have some sensitive data you could use Drupal's private directory or simply move your files outside your Drupal root.

To block .json files globally in your Drupal root try adding this into your .htaccess:

```
 <Files "*.json">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all 
 </Files>
```

Also don't forget to configure the AllowOverride flag in your virtual host.